# Redux state null in React-Native even after execution of the action being successful

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

Redux state is null, even after execution of the action being successful!

My app has a login button which when clicked, it triggers an action:

> src / Screen / Member / SignIn / index.js, line 40:
>   this.props.tryLogin (email, password)

In the action file:

> /src/actions/userActions.js

The action `tryLogin ()` is executed successfully, and there is the normal dispatch:

```
const action = userLoginSuccess (res);
dispatch (action);
```

The execution succeeds, and the app redirects to app home:

> /src/Screen/Public/Home/index.js

**The problem is right here, when I try to read the redux state:
in the file:**

> /src/Component/Menu/Left/index.js, line: 206

`mapStateToProps ()`,

The state is `null`, even with the action `userLoginSuccess ()` having been successfully executed !!!

My repository to test:
https://github.com/tmacedo2014/EstudoReactNative

Data to use in test login:
email: tiberius.macedo@gmail.com
pass: 123456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your action type. In [actions/userActions.js](https://github.com/tmacedo2014/EstudoReactNative/blob/9c02e9f49a29a3242b43320220bc05bbd0b268b2/src/actions/userActions.js#L4) you named the action constant `USER_LOGIN_SUCESS` but in [reducers/userReducer.js](https://github.com/tmacedo2014/EstudoReactNative/blob/9c02e9f49a29a3242b43320220bc05bbd0b268b2/src/reducers/userReducer.js#L1) you import `USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS`.

If you fix this typo, everything else looked like it was hooked up correctly.